# React-Navigation v4 pass state from child to parent on back press

Tags: react-hooks, react-native, react-navigation

I need to pass state from my child screen to the parent screen . I am having difficulties doing this. I am letting the user press a button to `navigate` to the child screen. After filling info in the child screen I am trying to pass the value back to the parent screen with `props.navigation.goBack()` Can someone help me out with this.

I am using react navigation v4

Parent screen:

```
const Parent = (props) => {
  const [day, setDay] = useState("");

  return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() =>props.navigation.navigate({ routeName: 'Child' })}>
        </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Child screen (I want to pass the `day` state back to the parent)

```
const Child = props => {
    const [day, setDay] = useState("");
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput onChange={(text)=> setDay(text)}/>
      <Button onPress={()=>props.navigation.goBack()}/>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Would it be possible to just navigate to the screen by name? so like you are doing it in your parent component ?

Comment: Oh you mean navigate back and send params? But how do I do that . I am aware of how to give the params in child component but in the parent how do I do that?

Comment: I mean if it has to be done with goBack... or if it possible with normal naviigation.navigate({ routeName: "Parent" }) somehow like this. if thats possible you can send params with it

Comment: Please could you show me how I have no idea because it is not working with normal naviigation.navigate({ routeName: "Parent" }) while giving it params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is not possible to use the normal navigation way maybe try to build your own back function and pass params with it.

Take a look at this maybe:

```
  goBack() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    navigation.goBack();
    navigation.setParam({ day: dayData});
  }
```

then the call would be :

```
<Button onPress={()=>this.goBack()}/>
```

you can get the param with :

```
this.props.navigation.getParam("day")
```

try it somehow like this - if it does not work try the calls with this.props.navigation...
or only with navigation.goBack() and so on because I am not sure wich syntax will work for you.